# having some trouble in casting void* to back to String

Tags: c, string, pointers, casting, void-pointers

When I try to run the following code, the program crashes:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* String;

int main() {
    char string1[] = "hello";
    void* try = &string1;
    String try2 = *(String*)try;
    printf("%s ",try2);
}
```

any Idea why?

Comment: Ugh, don't use that typedef.

Comment: The cast prevented the compiler from catching an error. But the program died anyway. The lesson?

Comment: what is so horrible about my typedef?

Comment: `typedef` that contains a direct `*` is considered a confusing programming styles by many.  Also in C, a _string_ is a sequence (typically an array) of characters.  You are defining `String` to be a pointer type.  Image the confusion of  `typedef int Double;  Double x = 3.1;`

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 2):

```
String try2 = *(String*)try;
```

is equivalent to

```
char* try2 = *(char**)try;
```

which presumably conflicts to your intention. You should write either

```
String try2 = try;
```

or simply

```
char *try2 = try;
```

Also note that casting can hide serious problems, so you should avoid using them when they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
 String try2=*(String*)try;
```

is wrong. You can get rid of the unnecessary (*harmful*) casts (*which actually hides the issue of mismatched datatype*) and simply write

```
 String try2 = try;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
try=&string1[0];
```

or

```
try=string1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String try2=*(String*)try;
```

is wrong.

You can have either

```
String try2=(String)try;
```

or

```
String try2=try; // Recommended style, since a void* can be safely cast into any other pointer type.
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `string` is `char[6]`, it is an array of `char`, and you can assing it to a char pointer:

```
char* p = string;
```

However the type of `&string` is `char(*)[6]`. It is a pointer to an array of 6 `char`, so you cannot assign it to `char**`, which is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. You need to assign it to a pointer to an array of 6 characters:

```
char (*pa)[6] = &string;
```

Thus the cast you made here:

```
(String*)try;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
( char**)try
```

Is incorrect, because `try` represents a pointer to an array of 6 char, and not a pointer to a pointer to char.

The pointer should be cast to the correct type, a pointer to an array of 6 char:

```
String* try2 = *( char(*)[6] )try;
```